# Oracle APEX Compare Two Items Values to Fire a Dynamic Action

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I want to create a Dynamic Action thats when my page item P2014_BALANCE < P2014_CURRENT_PRICE then P2014_CURRENT_PRICE gets the static value 0.
The problem is that i can't compare these two page items. I try to when section in my Dynamic Action to use Javascript expression like this:

```
if(apex.item( "P2014_CURRENT_PRICE " ).getValue() < apex.item( "P2014_CURRENT_PRICE " ).getValue()){
alert('Wrong Number');
};
```

but when my page loads gets an error (even Fire on Initialization = False).

I also try this:
[image]

still nothing.

Comment: When do you want to fire this dynamic action- is this on page load (if so do you need a dynamic action or can you use a computation instead ?) or when P2014_CURRENT_PRICE changes ? It would make sense if you explain the page flow. What is "gets an error" ? What is the error ?

Comment: Hi @Koen and thank toy for your answer. I want to fire this DA when P2014_CURRENT_PRICE changes. About the flow goes like this: When the page loads the item P2014_BALANCE gets the Balance from my table Payments. So when the user change the value to P2014_CURRENT_PRICE, i want to compare this two items and if P2014_CURRENT_PRICE > P2014_BALANCE to set the static value of P2014_CURRENT_PRICE item to 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a web application. All page items contain string values. So if you want to do number comparison, make them numbers:

```
if (Number(apex.item( "P2014_BALANCE" ).getValue()) < Number(apex.item( "P2014_CURRENT_PRICE" ).getValue())) {
alert('Wrong Number');
};
```

Note that in your example you have P2014_CURRENT_PRICE twice - that will always yield false anyways.

This is how you would implement this in a dynamic action. Note that I tried on 21.1 but it should be similar in 5 (consider upgrading):

Dynamic Action on **Change** of **Item** `P2014_CURRENT_PRICE` with client Side Condition of type **Javascript Expression**
**Source**:

```
apex.locale.toNumber(apex.item( "P2014_CURRENT_PRICE" ).getValue()) > apex.locale.toNumber(apex.item( "P2014_BALANCE" ).getValue())
```

True Action with Action **Set Value**
Set Type **Static Assignment**
**Value** "0"
Affected Element **Item** `P2014_CURRENT_PRICE`